# Is it possible to find frequency from circular membrane vibration?

Tags: waves, wavefunction, acoustics, fourier-transform, vibrations

Doing an experiment about circular membrane vibration, I was able to get different mode corresponding to the frequency in sinusoidal sound.

And at that point, I have a question about it. Is it possible to do reversely, more specifically, is there a way to recover frequency from given wave function $\psi(t, r, \theta)$? If there is, can you explain how to do it?

By the way, I did some googling, and it says ...

> At one of these peaks, we will have a Fourier coefficient for every spatial location in the image. These Fourier coefficients give the vibration mode shape with amplitude corresponding to the amount of motion and phase corresponding to fixed phase relation between points.
>
> *The Visual Microphone: Passive Recovery of Sound from Video (http://data.csail.mit.edu/vidmag/VisualMic/)*

But, I don't have any idea about how to get Fourier coefficient from a video of vibration of circular membrane.

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane) for a start.

Comment: From a brief look on the paper you provided, it seems they use some Computer Vision techniques to extract local phase information and then average that (after temporal alignment in respect to a reference frame, which is most often the first acquired frame) over the global coordinate system to extract global motion information. The topic seems to be somewhat involved. I suggest you try and implement the proposed solution in the paper (or a simplified version of it as a first try) and try to understand each step.